# Getting repeater fields after validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, repeater

I'm using javascript to create repeater fields for a Laravel project. I have nested repeater fields (repeater fields with child repeater fields) and have no problem with validating them or displaying error messages. Let's say I add two repeater fields (which every of those fields have one head input and one input for child repeaters) to my form. So I have four inputs and if I submit the form I'll get the validation errors like this (using `dd()` function) :

```
array:4 [▼
"topics.0.title" => array:2 [▶]
"topics.1.title" => array:2 [▶]
"topics.0.lessons.0.title" => array:2 [▶]
"topics.1.lessons.0.title" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

The problem is I want to loop repeaters fields and have the same fields (that I had before submitting form) When I back from validation. I know how to code but I don't know how can I get the number of head repeater fields that having errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but Try below code,i hope its help you:

```
$rules = array(
    'topics.*.title' => 'required',
    'topics.*.lessons.*.title' => 'required',
);
```